# Integrate $x e^{-x^4}$ Advanced Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm having trouble integrating the equation below. The book says "Hint: Let $u=x^2$, etc." I don't know how I would let $u=x^2$ since in order to do integration by parts I need $u\,dv$ and we only have $x$ not $x^2$ in the equation. If anyone could be point me in the right direction it would be appreciated!

$$x e^{-x^4}$$

P.S. Mathematica says the answer should be $\frac14 \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}(x^2)$.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int x e^{-x^4}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int e^{-u^2}\,du$ with the sub $u = x^2$

Comment: Put $y=x^2 \to dy =2xdx$ giving us $\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-y^2}dy = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\text{Erf}(y)$

Comment: By the way the title expression is different from the one in the body.

Comment: @Mario, thanks for the heads up; I've fixed it now.

Comment: Actually it's still different. The body has $-x^4$ in the exponent, the title has $x^{-4}$.

Comment: Woops, it's been a very long time since I've used Latex. I've actually fixed it now. X) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! Winther's explanation was outstanding.

Comment: See [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)), and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question appears to have been answered in the comments, so I'm putting this to take it off the unanswered queue.

> Put $y=x^2 \to dy =2xdx$ giving us $\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-y^2}dy = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\text{Erf}(y)$. --Winther